# Does Bach's lute partita BWV 997 Sarabande also appear as an orchestral piece?

Tags: classical-music, classical-guitar, baroque-period, j-s-bach

I am practicing the Bach lute suites and I am aware that a few of them also appear as works for other instruments (BWV 1000 is also the fugue from the first violin sonata, for example).
My question is around the Sarabande from Lute Partita in C Minor, BWV 997. I feel like I have heard this as an orchestral piece of some sort, but I can't seem to find what I'm looking for. Can anyone identify this, or am I simply imagining things?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You *might* be confusing this with the finale of the St Matthews passion, BWV 244, which resembles this piece very much and is performed way more often.

Comment: @KilianFoth Thank you!!! My mistake, they clearly are not the same throughout, but that's definitely what I was thinking of. Thanks for the help!